# Swift RunLoop: get notified on currentMode change

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, nsrunloop, runloop

I'm interested in getting notified when the [currentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1412652-currentmode) property of the [RunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop) class changes, more specifically, I'm interested in getting an event when the mode is entering `.tracking` state.

I've tried two different approaches:

This one simply doesn't work, what could be wrong with it?:

```
import Foundation
public final class RunLoopTracker {
    private let runLoop: RunLoop

    private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    public init(runLoop: RunLoop) {
        self.runLoop = runLoop
    }


    public func attach() {
        observation = runLoop.observe(\.currentMode) { runLoop, change in
            print(change)
        }
    }
}
```

This one works, but fires only once. I'd like to get the block executed each time the `RunLoop` enters the specific mode:

```
import Foundation

public final class RunLoopTracker2 {
    private let runLoop: RunLoop

    private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    public init(runLoop: RunLoop) {
        self.runLoop = runLoop
    }


    public func attach() {
        runLoop.perform(inModes: [.tracking]) {
            print("Entering the tracking mode, send notification")
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the solution to these two problems or a different approach to track `RunLoop.currentMode` changes?

Comment: Did you tried a runLoop extension with a didSet observer on mode ?

Comment: That wouldn't work, I'd like to observe the change of the `RunLoop.main`, I couldn't just "subclass" it, since it's provided by the system

Comment: I did not wrote subclass : add an extension to current RunLoop class

Comment: Could you provide the example?

Comment: I checked again and this property does not exists as it in RunLoop definition. BTW I check on internet and it seems that RunLoop can not change. Found [this entry](https://khorbushko.github.io/article/2020/11/29/runloop-in-depth.html) on GitHub . It has one paragraph the state : "RunLoop has few Modes with Source/Timer/Observer in it. Only ONE Mode can be active at once, and it’s called current. To switch between modes u need to exit Loop and set a new mode. Why? just to separate Source/Timer/Observer and make them not affect each other."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished with the following solution:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class RunLoopModeTracker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isTracking = false

    private let runLoop: RunLoop
    private var taskSet = false

    public init(runLoop: RunLoop = .main) {
        self.runLoop = runLoop
        submitTaskForTrackingMode()
    }


    private func submitTaskForTrackingMode() {
        if !taskSet {
            runLoop.perform(inModes: [.tracking]) { [weak self] in
                self?.notify()
            }
            taskSet = true
        }
    }

    private func notify() {
        isTracking = true
        taskSet = false
        submitTaskForDefaultMode()
    }


    private func submitTaskForDefaultMode() {
        if !taskSet {
            runLoop.perform(inModes: [.default]) { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else {return}
                self.isTracking = false
                self.submitTaskForTrackingMode()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then at call site I just use it like this:

```
@StateObject private var runLoopTracker = RunLoopModeTracker()
/// ...
.onChange(of: runLoopTracker.isTracking) { isTracking                 
/// isTracking value has changed to true
}
```

Essentially, the idea is to add the task for both the `default` and the `tracking` modes and once the runloop enters any of those, update the status correspondingly.