# Get notified each time RunLoop enters .tracking mode

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, key-value-observing, runloop

How can I track and get notified each time the [RunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/mode/1622929-tracking)'s `currentMode` property changes to [.tracking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift RunLoop: get notified on currentMode change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309274/swift-runloop-get-notified-on-currentmode-change)

Comment: No, this doesn't answer my question. There is no answer.